# Word for holding something thats not yours

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

My Aunt is holding onto savings bonds my grandparents bought me. There’s a single word I’m looking for that means she’s holding them & won’t give them to me (I’m in my 40’s)

Comment: Stealing? Embezzling?...You should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word could be used.

Comment: Are they legally yours or hers? (Unless it's in writing to the contrary, possession is 90% of the law.)

Comment: Legally mine, in my name & it says my grandfather’s name as only other person that can cash them

Comment: I believe the legal term is *conversion*, which means depriving someone of their full rights of ownership. But check with law.se  . Hiding stuff from someone is a pretty classic example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My aunt is **withholding** savings bonds that my grandparents bought for
> me.

**withhold** (v.)

> To keep back; to keep in one's possession (what belongs to, is due to,
> or is desired by another); to refrain from giving, granting, or
> allowing. OED

---

> Can it be possible that my brother is **withholding** my inheritance?
> [Philippa Gregory; *Three Sisters, Three Queens*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Three_Sisters_Three_Queens/_B0gDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=he%20was%20withholding%20my%20inheritance&pg=PA131&printsec=frontcover)

> You have my inheritance, which you are **withholding** from me. [A.
> Oppenheimer and N. Oppenheimer; *Between Rome and Babylon*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Between_Rome_and_Babylon/BPkfQl2iDx8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=he%20was%20withholding%20my%20inheritance&pg=PA164&printsec=frontcover)

> You are impeding my lifestyle, my way of life. **Withholding** what is
> rightfully mine. [Scott Wellinger; *The Deposition*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Deposition/pFMfDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=withholding%20what%20is%20rightfully%20mine&pg=PT22&printsec=frontcover)

> **Withholding** information means keeping secrets from or misrepresenting the facts to the public. [The Princeton Review;
> *MCAT*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/MCAT/lAeQOLLxlrYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=withholding%20means%20you%20are%20%20keeping%20what%20is&pg=PA319&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word [deprive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprive) (v.)

> 1. to take something away from
>
> > e.g. **deprived** him of his professorship

> 2. to withhold something from
>
> > e.g. **deprived** a citizen of her rights

Your Aunt is depriving you of the savings bond which is rightfully yours, as given by your grandmother.